# AngularFire SSR hosting function defaults to uscentra1. How do you change it?

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I have followed this [guide](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/deploy/getting-started.md) to setup my angular app with ssr. It currently defaults to uscentral1 region when deploying my angular app. I cant seem to find a way to change the region where the function is deploy to. I currently use `ng deploy` to deploy my app. I tried changing the deploy settings in angular.json file but nothing changed. I added a the following to angular.json but the function still deployed to uscentral1

```
        "deploy": {
          "builder": "@angular/fire:deploy",
          "options": {
            "functionsNodeVersion": 12,
            "ssr": true,
            "region": "europe-west6"
          }
```

I am using Angular 11, Firebase 8.2.4 and AngularFire 6.1.4.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: guessing it needs to be here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/deploy/getting-started.md#configuring-cloud-functions

Comment: Yeap I tried that but it didn't work. You can see the example code in my question. I attempted that